# Change value using for in loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I am trying to write a `for in` loop function that changes any value that is greater than `20` to `0`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
function greaterThan20(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] > 20) {
      obj[key] = 0;
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

Comment: Why don't use Array's `filter()`?

Comment: do you have a question or a problem with your current solution? @Mamun there is nothing to filter, just changing values

Comment: @Slai Write a function called greaterThan20 that takes in an object. Write a for in loop that loops over the object and changes any value that is great than 20 to 0. Return the updated object.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your function unless any of the values are strings .. then it would be something like `if (+obj[key] > 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
function greaterThan20(obj){
  for(var key in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          if(obj[key] > 20){
            obj[key] = 0;
          }
      }
  }
  return obj;
}
var obj = {'one':10,'two':25,'three':30}
console.log(greaterThan20(obj))
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is function to replace value greater thn 20

```
function greaterThan20(obj){
  for (int a=0;a<obj.length;a++){
    if (obj[i] > 20){
      obj[i] = 0;
    }
  }
 return obj
}
```